# How Do I configure Spring View Resolver to Ignore a Specific Url and Not Look for Its .jsp?

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I am working on a web application using Spring MVC architecture. I have a controller method that will be called by an ajax post(). The request mapper in the controller has a ".html" (meant for some cleanup task)for which the Spring Internal view resolver is trying to find a matching .JSP file and throws a 404 Not Found error. I donot want to create a .JSP which is not useful in my case. I need some help to determine if there is any setting in Spring Context xml to let the view resolver ignore this url and not to look for its .JSP file.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/clearSession.html")
    public void unloadDAOSession(HttpServletRequest request) {...}
```

the InternalViewResolver is looking for clearSession.jsp which throws a 404 Resource Not found. I dont want to create a JSP which is of no use.

Are there any application Context settings in the view resolver to ignore this ".html" file and not to look for its ".jsp"?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though the return type is `void` it only means that the view name will be resolved based on the URL as you have seen.

One way to avoid view resoluion is to annotate the response with `@ResponseBody` or
 bypass the view resolver by tweaking your return type to something like

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/clearSession.html")
public ResponseEntity<String> unloadDAOSession(HttpServletRequest request) {
   ...
    return new ResponseEntity<String>("OK",HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
}
```

This way instead of forwarding to a view, your just adding a header and an empty body to the response stream

Comment: I think if we make the response stream as null, there might be some potential issues with closing of http connections. Is there any other way instead of sending just empty content in the response stream?

Comment: Also, when i tried to add the ResponseEntity, i get this : The constructor ResponseEntity<String>(String, int) is undefined

Comment: Could you let me know is it safe to use the @responseBody on a void method?

Comment: like in this code : @RequestMapping(value = "/updateSomeData" method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody void updateDataThatDoesntRequireClientToBeNotified(...) {
    ...
}

Answer (score 0):

In case of use of ajax and traditional controller, the best approach is write the your controller for answare to the page rendering as you had done adn then write a rest end-point layer for answare to ajax request.

I just give you some piece of code for clearing what I want say:

Controller layer:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/yourPage")
public void yourPage(Model mode) {...}
```

Rest layer:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/yourAjax")
public ResponseEntity<String> yourAjax(@RequstBody YoutDTOClass postBody) {
   ...
    return ResponseEntity.created(...).build();
}



class YoutDTOClass{
// your properties
....
```

}

with this schema you separate the service layer for your ajax request and the classic web layer for serving the your page.

Just an hint don't use a pattern like /yourPage.html but you should prefare a pattern like /youtPage.This balically for banefit of the view resolver abstraction of Spring, you should let to springMVC to resolve the actual view.

Even for the ajax you should use the accept header for ask the correct rappresentation of your resource and the ResponseEntity should be used for return a 201 Http status for say to your browser that the your resource was created. remember that a better approach should prefere the use of http method in REST world and then for delete a session you should be prefare delte method for delete a session and put http method for update the sate of the session.

I hope that this can help you

Comment: Thanks Vaudi, i will try this and let you know.